# How to pass some value to another action in chicagoboss?

Tags: web-applications, erlang, chicagoboss

I wrote some like that:

```
login('POST', []) ->
    ....
            case Client:check_password(Req:post_param("password")) of
                true ->
                    {redirect, [{controller, "chat"}, {action, "live"}], [{username, Name}, {gender, Gender}]};
    ....
    end.
```

how to let the live action in chat controller receive the name and gender information?
I wrote:

```
live('GET', [Req]) ->
   Name=Req:post_param("username"),
   ....
   {ok, [{username, Name}, {gender, Gender}]}
```

But it doesn't work, could anyone can help me>

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your redirect is most likely not what you intended.

If you check [the controller API documentation](http://chicagoboss.org/api-controller.html) you will notice that the second proplist refers to request headers, not parameters (`{redirect, Location, Headers::proplist()}`). This means that you could access the values in your `live/2` like this `Req:header("HEADERNAME")`.

Secondly, in the definition of your `live/2` controller function, you are assuming that you have captured a URL parameter (which you reference as `Req`). This is not reflected in your redirect in the `login` controller function. So what you can do is change the definition of your `live/2` to `live('GET', [Username, Gender])`, this means you would have to call it like this `/live/a-username/the-users-gender`, then change the redirect to `{redirect, [{controller, "chat"}, {action, "live"}, {username, Name}, {gender, Gender}]}`.

However, I would recommend that you use sessions instead. Implement a `before_/1` method on your controller and make sure that your module definition contains both the request and session_id parameters (check [the](http://chicagoboss.org/api-controller.html) [documentation](http://chicagoboss.org/api-session.html)). Now you can just use the sessions API to pass around any session related values (it also has the benefit that you can clean up your controller functions - add a third parameter and simply distinguish between requests based on  `before_/1` results).

For example you could then have:

```
live('GET', [], undefined) -> 
    % redirect to the login page
live('GET', [], UserObject) ->
    {ok, [{username, UserObject:username()}, {gender, UserObject:gender()}]}.
```